# Custom Ticks for Image3D?

Tags: graphics3d, image3d

Is it possible to make user-defined ticks in an `Image3D`? (Wizardly solutions will be appreciated, too.) With

```
Image3D[Import["ExampleData/CTengine.tiff"], Boxed -> True, Axes -> True
 (*,Ticks -> {x,y,z}*)
]
```

I get

[image]

However, if I uncomment `Ticks`, I get a message

> Unknown option Ticks in Image3D[....]

---

`Ticks` I prepared for something else, but can be used here.

```
x = {{0, 0}, {75, Pi/4}, {150, Pi/2}, {225, 3 Pi/4}, {300, Pi}};
y = {{0, 0.0}, {75, 0.5}, {150, 1.0}, {225, 1.5}, {300, 2.0}};
z = Table[{i, i}, {i, 0, 8, 2}];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mydata = Import["ExampleData/CTengine.tiff"];

Show[Image3D[mydata], 
 Axes -> True, 
 Ticks ->
  {
   {{0, 0}, {75, π/4}, {150, π/2}, {225, 3 π/4}, {300, π}},
   {{0, 0.0}, {75, 0.5}, {150, 1.0}, {225, 1.5}, {300, 2.0}},
   Table[{i, i}, {i, 0, 80, 20}]
  }
 ]
```